# Ubuntu partition is showing in windows but not readable

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am new to ubuntu. During installation of **Ubuntu 15.04 vivid vervet** , I created partitions for ubuntu filesystem as **Ext2** using windows partitioning tool.I created partitions for Boot loader information and ubuntu file system. After ubuntu installation, ubuntu partitions are showing in windows as local disks ,but not readable. When I tried to open it, a message that the partition is corrupted was shown and asked to format the disk. I dont want access for ubuntu file from windows.

- What is the cause of this ?
- How can I hide this ubuntu partition in windows ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This site is only about Ubuntu. Your question is about Windows. You would get better answers if you ask on e.g. [superusers.com](http://superuser.com/). All I can tell is Windows can't read EXT without extra drivers. Take a look at [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the specified question. Abhishek is not asking how to access the Ubuntu partitions, but how to hide them. I cover this issue [in this Web page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work is that windows does not know how to read ext2 filesystems.

I am not aware of a method to block windows from seeing the partitions, Does it assign the ext2 partition a drive letter?

Comment: Yes. There is letter assigned for each partitions. I've created partitions for Boot loader information and ubuntu file system.

Comment: In that case you can go into Disk Management, right click on the drive and remove the drive letter